# How to skip a PYTHON line code in the debugger?

Tags: python, pygame

I am creating a game using pygame, but when I open the debugger there seems to be an error in the pygame importing process. It doesn't affect the game but I would like to jump to a specific code in the game.

Comment: u want to comment out that code or want to skip error message ?

Comment: How do you open it in debugger? with `pdb`?

Comment: Did my answer solve your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()` before the line you want to skip to. Then start your program, it'll stop right on that line.

If this is a single file you can open the program using the debugger (`pdb`) and if the line you want to jump is 30, in the debugger prompt run `until`

```
(Pdb) until 30
```

In the debugger, it's also possible to set a break point using `break` command in a specific file and the `continue` program

```
(Pdb) break /path/to/file.py:30
(Pdb) continue
```